# Retrieve SMS Message sent by a service (which shows up as a name rather than number)

Tags: android, sms

1. What are the messages (SMS) sent by banks, mobile networks etc. (like TM-VODAFONE) called. I was having a hard time doing a search query for this.
2. I want to search the messages inbox and find out such messages.I know that we can query the `SMS_INBOX` table, but can I do a search using such name? Or is each message associated with a contact id or something?
3. I would also like to know how these messages are sent so that all mobiles display such a name rather than a number, and i believe only one organization can register / use such a name for security purposes

EDIT : At least can somebody say the name of this kind of message, so that i can do a proper search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I dont know what such messages are called.
2. The `address` parameter contains the name of the sender, its like phone number for normal contacts and the name for the senders that you require.

You can loop through all the messages in the inbox, compare the address field of each message.

1. No idea.